# How to show SignIn and register forms in a single page in Symfony 1.3/1.4?

Tags: embed, symfony-1.4

I want to show the users on my homepage , a signin and a register form side by side.

how do i do it?...even using embedform() didnot yield results,same was the case with ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelations Plugin.

The project is built using symfony 1.4.
Appreciate your help..thanks!

Comment: How did you solve it ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply have two separate form in your view, with two distinct action url.

```
<div id="leftSide">
  <form action="ulr_to_signin_action">
    <?php $signinForm->render(); ?>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="rightSide">
  <form action="ulr_to_register_action">
    <?php $registerForm->render(); ?>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to handle submitting each form and redring one view ?